# Show API data to another HTML

Tags: javascript, css, api

I'm kinda new to API's, I want to create a film webpage, in the home page I have successfully shown some movies and info. But my question is, how can I create a new info page of every movie (without creating and html for every movie) What topic should I investigate to do this?

Comment: create different `divs` and make them visible on user click only if you want to use vanilla js otherwise use react or vue etc.

Comment: Are you using any framework or just a html, css, and javascript ?

Comment: @Coder just using html, css and JavaScript

Comment: Create a javascript function eg: show(1),  in this function 1 is id for perticular movie, then display whole data from javascript function only